# Where the prototype objects like HTMLParagraphElement are laying in the BOM tree?

Tags: javascript

I want to have a clear understanding of the BOM structure.

**Question 1**: For example I have an html document and there are only one element `<p id="1"> </p>` iside `<body></body>`. When a browser analizes the html document it starts to build the DOM tree inside the BOM tree and my paragraph element is converted into a `p` object who is put in the determined place of the DOM tree - `window.document.lastChild(I have got the html object).lastChile(I have got the html object).firstChild(I have got the p object).`The question is **where are the all objects of the p object prototype chain are situated - HTMLParagraphElement, HTMLElement, Element, Node?** If I am taking the HTMLParagraphElement object (`document.getElementById("1").__proto__;`) and asking "Who is your parent?" (`(document.getElementById("1").__proto__.parentNode;)`) then some mistake appears  **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**.

**Question 2**: there was a thought in my mind that all prototype objects (HTMLElement, Element, Node...) are laying in the root of the window object (because all programmer's objects and prototype objects are laying the root of the window object). I looked at this window root and saw that there are a lot of consctructor functions (which have the same names as prototype objects (function HTMLElement(), function Element(), function Node()...). Each of These functions has **__proto__ property and constructor property at the same time**. How is it possible that constructor functions have prototypes? A constructor function just is throwing properties (like this.propname) inside a new object. I thought that only "typical" object (`var obj={name:1};`) is able to contain a prototype property. **For what this prototype is needed for a function?**

**Question 3**: It turned out that a window object has some prototype object with the same name and the prototype chain goes on. **Where are these prototype objects are laying in a window object?** I thought that a window object is laying on the top of the objects hierarchy. As I see the more I know about the javascript the more I understand that I know nothing. Help me, please, to understand it.
[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

Comment: BOM - browser object model. this is the model of the window object. DOM is laying inside of the BOM (window.document - DOM).

Comment: One question per question, please. Also, please use paragraphs, bullets, etc., to break up your text. Right now the combination of no whitespace and an overuse of bold is making this very difficult to read.

Comment: For the first two questions, please read about [the `__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). It is roughly equivalent the "class" or "type" of the instance you are examining, so it makes no sense to call an instance method or access an instance property on it.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#window

Comment: object properties can point back to the whole object, like `window.window.window`

Answer (score 1):

First, almost no object has a `__proto__` property. Don't rust the developer tools which display it as an own property. `__proto__` is a not-much-standard accessor property defined in `Object.prototype` which provides access to the internal [[Prototype]] slot of an object.

All ordinary objects have an internal [[Prototype]] slot. It determines from which other object the former one inherits from.

For example, `[]` creates an array whose [[Prototype]] is `Array.prototype`, where methods like `push` and `forEach` are defined.

All constructors have a `prototype` property. When instantiated, the [[Prototype]] of the instance will point to the value of the `prototype` of the constructor at that moment.

Constructors are function objects, so it makes sense they inherit function methods. That is, their [[Prototype]] is usually `Function.prototype` or an object which inherits from it.

Some examples:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf([]); // Array.prototype
Object.getPrototypeOf(Array);    // Function.prototype
Object.getPrototypeOf(Function); // Function.prototype
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object);   // Function.prototype
Object.getPrototypeOf(Array.prototype);    // Object.prototype
Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype); // Object.prototype
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype);   // null
```

The reason you got an "Illegal invocation" exception is because `parentNode` is defined in `Node.prototype`, from which all nodes inherit from (not necessarily directly). `parentNode` is defined as a getter which returns the parent of the node on which the property was accessed.

```
document.documentElement.parentNode; // document
document.documentElement.hasOwnProperty('parentNode'); // false
Node.prototype.hasOwnProperty('parentNode'); // true
```

Then, if you use `Node.prototype.parentNode`, if will attempt to retrieve the parent node of `Node.prototype` , but `Node.prototype` is not a node. Therefore, it throws. But you could use something like

```
Reflect.get(Node.prototype, 'parentNode', document.documentElement); // document
```

Finally, objects are not required to be stored somewhere in a tree rooted at the global object. Otherwise, they could not be garbage collected! Objects are just stored in memory, and they can be referenced by other objects or not.

```
(function() {
  var obj = {}; // This object is not referenced anywhere
})();
```