# What is "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation” in Chrome?

Tags: javascript

I have a question.Imagine that we have such html document:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="1">Hi</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I am writing `document.getElementById("1").__proto__;` - I have got the HTMLParagraphElement object. It is the first prototype object in the chain (HTMLParagraphElement--> HTMLElement --> Element--> Node-->...) of the p object prototypes. As the Node object is laying in this chain so all its properties and methods are available for the HTMLParagraphElement object. And when I am writing `document.getElementById("1").__proto__.parentNode;` a browser gives me

**Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**.
What does it mean? And how can I know where exactly this HTMLParagraphElement object is connected to the BOM? For example, if I am writing var x=10; - it is an object and it is connected to the root of the window object (window.x;). I want to have a clear understanding of the structure of the BOM.

Comment: I'd guess `.parentNode` uses/is a ES6 getter. Reading `.parentNode` doesn't just access the variable, it calls the getter function and return the result. And inside that function, there's something the browser doesn't allow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where the prototype objects like HTMLParagraphElement are laying in the BOM tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152158/where-the-prototype-objects-like-htmlparagraphelement-are-laying-in-the-bom-tree)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the parentNode of an element, you should directly do:

```
document.getElementById("1").parentNode
```

The above line would return a reference to the `<body>` node and is appropriate for traversing up the DOM.

Otherwise,

```
document.getElementById("1").__proto__.parentNode
```

would mean that you are trying to get the parentNode of the class/type `HTMLParagraphElement` which isn't an element but rather a type of element: types of elements don't have parentNodes.

Something more appropriate to do with `__proto__` would be:

```
document.getElementById("1").__proto__.__proto__
```

The above line would give you the `HtmlElement` class, although this isn't very useful to have.

Regarding `var x`, it should be noted that the variables defined in javascript are not attached to the DOM, and global variables are added to `window`. `window` is connected to the DOM by `window.document`, which in short is accessed by just typing `document....` commands.

Comment: Yes, I want to get  the parentNode of the prototype object HTMLParagraphElement, because this property is defined in its properties. I think that if it is defined it has to work correctly, but it gives "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation". I want to know more about the BOM structure

Comment: @Damon, It would make no sense to run `HTMLParagraphElement.prototype.parentNode` in your code as written. `parentNode` is a built-in function in element types and will try to evaluate itself without doing `.parentNode()`. In trying to  access `.parentNode`, it will fail as `HTMLParagraphElement.prototype` is not in the DOM tree. To clarify `document.getElementById("1")` is in the DOM tree and `HTMLParagraphElement` is not. `HTMLParagraphElement` only exists as a javascript type wrapper located at `window.HTMLParagraphElement` and isn't in the DOM.

Comment: so how can I navigate (to understand its structure) in the BOM? how can I get the place in the BOM where, for example, the HTMLElement, Element, Node, function-constructor Array(), function-constructor Function(), function-constructor Object(), Array.protorype, Function.prototype..... ARE CONNECTED TO THE BOM? are there (in the BOM) some prorerties or methods for navigation in the BOM?

Comment: Most of these are all exposed directly in `window`. i.e. window.Node, window.HTMLElement are all defined. For viewing the hierarchy, this is what you would use `__proto__` for: i.e `HTMLElement.__proto__` is Element. `Element.__proto__` is Node.